# hiding https port in url and redirection in Tomcat 7

Tags: redirect, https, tomcat7

I am facing two issues.

1. Hiding https port in URL: My site is hosted here https://www.bhcds.com:8443/bham/#/login and I wan't to get rid of the port number.
2. Redirection: When I type www.bhcds.com it redirects to the url https://www.bhcds.com:8443/bham/#/login in IE and Safari, but in Chrome and Firefox it stops redirecting second time onwards.

This is my tomcat server.xml configuration snippet.

```
    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="C:\certificate\xyz.jks" keystorePass="password"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You're using a non-standard port, therefore you **MUST** include the port in the URL. If you remove the port number from the url, then the browser will try to connect to the standard port, which is `443`.

Comment: I don't mind changing port numbers in server.xml, I just want to have a clean url like gmail or any other secure site. If by non standard port you meant 8443, I changed it to 443, but that dint work as well.

Comment: if you're serving up https on port 443, then you DON'T need the port in the url, because that's the default port.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Marc, I am running Tomcat on Windows with NO Apache. How can I make tomcat to use port 443? Merely replacing the  port 8443 with 443 doesn't help (I also tried adding another connector at port 8443). There are some solutions asking to modify IP tables rules, but I am on windows.